# Does when() in Mockito verify invocation with strict parameter?

Tags: java, mockito

I am curious if `when(mock.method(SPECIFIC_PARAM)).thenReturn(RETURN_VAlUE);` checks for invocation of method. Or should I do `verify(mock).method(SPECIFIC_PARAM);` to make sure the method has been invoked?

Comment: Have you done any experiments to try to find out?

Comment: Should've done that. @jonrsharpe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` or `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)`, you will get an UnnecessaryStubbingException after running a test if you provided a mock that is not used.

You can avoid this by setting `@MockitoSettings(strictness = Strictness.LENIENT)` if you want to.

But even with the UnnecessaryStubbingException, it's still better to do an actual verify inside your test for readability. Your 'verify' can also be stricter than your stub, e.g:

```
when(mock.method(anyCollection())).thenReturn(...)
...
mock.method(collection);
...
verify(mock).method(argThat(collection -> collection.size()==1));
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically `when(mock.method(SPECIFIC_PARAM)).thenReturn(RETURN_VAlUE);` signifies that when the method is invoked on the mock then the specified value is returned. The `when`is used to configure the mocking, so it doesn't perform any verifications. It is the `verify` that checks if a method is called.

Answer (score 0):

With the method `when(..).thenReturn(...)` you are defining a rule on the mock object, in your particular case, you are instructing the mock object to return "RETURN_VALUE" when the method `mock.method` is invoked with input parameter "SPECIFIC_PARAM".
You are actually not asserting anything over the mock object.
Instead, you can check the effective invocation of the mock's method, by using `verify(mock)`, as you did in your description.
For example, this is what you should expect when your method is not invoked:

`got: <Wanted but not invoked: mock.method(SPECIFIC_PARAM);`